# When i try to read a file in MainActivity it appears to be blank while other Activities can read the created file

Tags: java, android, backend, mobile-application

Problem - when i try to read the file LoginCredentials.txt, it comes out to be empty for some reason, Other activities are able to read it but not MainActivity. It can be because of the CheckFirstTimeRun code i am using under onCreate of MainActivity but i am not sure.

This is the CreateUserID.class from which i am creating a file,

```
public class CreateUserID extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText usernameField;
private EditText passwordField;

public String userid;
public String userpass;

private final String File_Name = "LoginCredentials.txt";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user_id);

    usernameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Username);
    passwordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Password);

}
public void MakeAccount(View v) throws IOException {

    userid = usernameField.getText().toString();
    userpass = passwordField.getText().toString();

    String x=null;
    x=userid+userpass;

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(File_Name,MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(x.getBytes());
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finish();
}
}
```

And here is the MainActivity.class which is supposed to read the file.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected EditText Authentication_Username;
protected EditText Authentication_Password;
protected String File_Name = "LoginCredentials.txt";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences wmbPreference = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);
    if (isFirstRun)
    {

        Intent k = new Intent(this,CreateUserID.class);
        startActivity(k);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
        editor.commit();
    }

}

public void Verify_User(View v) {
    Authentication_Username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Username);
    Authentication_Password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Password);

    String Match_Username = Authentication_Username.getText().toString();
    String Match_Password = Authentication_Password.getText().toString();

    String Collected = null;

    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(File_Name);
        byte[] a = new byte[fis.available()];
        while(fis.read(a)!=-1) {
            Collected = new String(a);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,Collected,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: There is only one activity that tries to read a file: MainActivity. Further String Collected will only contain the last bytes read and other garbage in the buff.

Answer (score 0):

change `String Collected = null;` to `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`
and `Collected = new String(a);` to  `sb.append(new String(a));` then pass `sb.toString()` to the `Toast.makeTest()` method